# What's the boost way to create a functor that binds out an argument

Tags: c++, boost, functor

I have need for a function pointer that takes two arguments and returns a string.

I would like to pass an adapter that wraps a function that takes one argument, and returns the string (i.e. discard one of the arguments).

I can trivially build my own adapter, that takes the 2 arguments, calls the wrapped function passing just the one argument through.

But I'd much rather have a simple way to create an adapter on the fly, if there is an easy way to do so in C++/boost?

Here's some details to make this a bit more concrete:

```
typedef boost::function<CString (int,int)> TooltipTextFn;

class MyCtrl
{
public:
    MyCtrl(TooltipTextFn callback = boost::bind(&MyCtrl::GetCellText, this, _1, _2)) : m_callback(callback) { }

    // QUESTION: how to trivially wrapper GetRowText to conform to TooltipTextFn by just discarding _2 ?!
    void UseRowText() { m_callback = boost::bind(&MyCtrl::GetRowText, this, _1, ??); }

private:

    CString GetCellText(int row, int column);
    CString GetRowText(int row);

    TooltipTextFn   m_callback;
}
```

Obviously, I can supply a member that adapts GetRowText to take two arguments and only passes the first to GetRowText() itself.

But is there already a boost binder / adapter that lets me do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By only providing `_1`, it will ignore the 2nd parameter given to `m_callback` and call `MyCtrl::GetRowText` with one `int` parameter.

```
void UseRowText() { m_callback = boost::bind(&MyCtrl::GetRowText, this, _1); }
```

On the other hand,

```
void UseRowText() { m_callback = boost::bind(&MyCtrl::GetRowText, this, _2); }
```

is also valid, where we send the 2nd parameter passed to `m_callback` into the 1st parameter of `MyCtrl::GetRowText`.

Comment: VS2008 SP 1 complains on this code.  I suspect that boost::bind is creating a functor that takes 1 argument (at least in your first example, which is the one I would need).  If there is a way to force the bind to generate a function-signature that matches TooltipTextFn while only using the one argument...

Comment: I don't seem to be running into this. I'm working under g++ and don't have readily available access to VS.

As an alternate suggestion, is it the `this` pointer in the default parameters of the constructor?

Comment: You're right.  The problem I was having was that a ternary conditional wouldn't compile X ? Y : Z.  But if I explicitly did an X = Y; then things were fine.  Thanks. :)